# CPS Coroutines: Why does this example require exhaust?

Tags: haskell, monads, coroutine, continuations

I am trying to figure out [the coroutines example](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Haskell/Continuation_passing_style#Example:_coroutines) from the **CPS** chapter from **wikibooks/Haskell**, but I cannot understand why the `runCoroutineT` function requires `. (<* exhaust)` at the end, if I change the function from

```
runCoroutineT = flip evalStateT [] . flip runContT return . runCoroutineT' . (<* exhaust)
```

to

```
runCoroutineT = flip evalStateT [] . flip runContT return . runCoroutineT'
```

the example seems to [keep working](https://repl.it/repls/ExtrasmallInsignificantRom)(Take a look at the 56-th line)
Could anyone please explain if there is a mistake?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It doesn't look to me like it works. The example program you linked to ends with

```
example = runCoroutineT $ do
    fork $ replicateM_ 3 (printOne 3)
    fork $ replicateM_ 4 (printOne 4)
    replicateM_ 2 (printOne 2)
```

But when run, not all of the 4s are printed:

```
3
4
3
2
4
3
2
4
```

There should be four of them!

The point of `exhaust` is to finish off all threads that are waiting to run, and when you run without it some threads may not get to finish.